# How to orderby multiple meta fields if some fields are empty

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-query, order, meta-value

I'm trying to orderby meta fields value, but sometimes those values are empty :

A >
`title` = 'The apartment',
`wpcf-f-french-operating-title` = ' ',
`wpcf-f-order-title` = '**A**partment'

B >
`title` = 'The Bulldog movie',
`wpcf-f-french-operating-title` = '**B**ulldog film',
`wpcf-f-order-title` = ' '

C >
`title` = '**C**runch',
`wpcf-f-french-operating-title` = ' ',
`wpcf-f-order-title` = ' '

...

`wpcf-f-order-title` priors to `wpcf-f-french-operating-title` priors to `title`

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'taxonomy_section_sort_order' );

function taxonomy_section_sort_order( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if ( $query->is_tax('section') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Args
        $meta_query =   array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'status' => array(
                    'key' => '_status',
                    'value' => ['approved','programmed'],
                    'compare' => 'IN',
            ),
            array ( 
                'relation' => 'OR',
                'empty_order_title' => array(
                    'key' => 'wpcf-f-order-title',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                ),
                'order_title' => array(
                    'key' => 'wpcf-f-order-title',
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                'empty_french_title' => array(
                    'key' => 'wpcf-f-french-operating-title',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                ),
                'french_title' => array(
                    'key' => 'wpcf-f-french-operating-title',
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                ),
            ),
        );

        // Set meta queries 
        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 100);

        // Multiple order
        $query->set('orderby', array('order_title' => 'ASC', 'french_title' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC'));

        return $query;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

This fails in ordering posts.
Any ideas ? Thanks a lot